# SipDemo Outgoing Call

Tags: android, sip, sipdroid, csip-simple

I've totally involved by SipDemo app. I am making **Sip call** and it is done. I can hear voice but other sip person is **unable to hear** my voice.

This is my Registration code:-

```
 public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    //sipcallid
   // username and password should be same
 //   sipAddress = "101@217.xx.xxx.xxx";
    String domain =  sipAddress.substring(sipAddress.indexOf('@')+1);
    String username = sipAddress.substring(0,sipAddress.indexOf('@'));
    Toast.makeText(outcall.this, "domain = "+domain+" username "+username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword("123456");
        builder.setOutboundProxy(domain);
        builder.setDisplayName(username);
        builder.setAuthUserName(username);
        //builder.setDisplayName(username);
       // builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
       // builder.setSendKeepAlive(true);

        me = builder.build();

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                   updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                    updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                }
            });
    } catch (SipException se) {
        updateStatus("Connection error.");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my Initiate call:-

```
    // sipcallid = "rahul22@sip2sip.info";
    updateStatus(sipcallid);

    try {
          SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                //call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
                updateStatus1("on call established");

            }
            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus1("on call end");
                 finish();
            }



        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipcallid, listener, 30);

        updateStatus1(""+call.getState());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(outcall.this, "Error when trying to close manager"+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Toast.makeText(outcall.this, "ee"+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please Except.   I can hear the voice of other person but other person can't hear my voice.

please help me!. Thank you for your timing.

Comment: Hey I work on the same code and I didnt connect to my sip server. Did you find any solution? Please contact me.

Answer (score 1):

It raise when your IP adress is NAT address usually. Android not support NAT by default. For supporting with NAT you will use other external libraries such as CSipSimple.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you call call.toggleMute()

Could it be that you are muting the microphone? The SipDemo app has a button which unmutes the microphone.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (call == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null && call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Maybe you just mute the microphone when you initiate the call but never unmute?